# PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in IIS

Tags: php, iis

The same code works in Xampp. But if try to run it on IIS below error occurs.
"PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect()"
I'm stuck with this error from couple of days. 
I tried changing my php.in . My phpinfo.php points to correct .ini file
Please suggest me a way.

part of my php.ini file:

```
           extension=php_mbstring.dll
           extension=php_exif.dll     
           extension=php_mysql.dll
           extension=php_mysqli.dll
           extension=php_mysql_libmysql.dll
```

Comment: Does `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` (or `$ php -i`) show MySQL support is enabled?

Comment: Does mysqli or PDO work instead?

Comment: Check this article , http://www.webmasterworld.com/php/4393614.htm

Comment: Try copy your  php.ini to the C:\Windows directory